# mysql performance in aggregation functions

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I wonder about the aggregate functions of MySql.

Will the following query:

```
select sum(c / 1000) from t;
```

Have better performance than:

```
select sum(c) / 1000 from t;
```

when `t` is a big table?

Comment: I believe `select sum(c) / 1000 from t;` is faster. because it divide only once when `SUM` is ready. but first variant divides per every row.

Comment: Agree with Alex, second option will save you as many divisions as there will be rows (-1) so logically it has to be faster..

Comment: you could just as easily typed that into the sql console as here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to test this, but I have no idea what your definition of "big table" is.

For this test case, I used a database table with 1,063,527 rows of data in (Again, your data set may be bigger)

The times were as follows;

SELECT sum(field / 1000) FROM table;

```
0.344   0.359   0.625   0.390   0.594   0.359
```

SELECT sum(field) / 1000 FROM table;

```
0.234   0.390   0.219   0.438   0.203   0.485
```

**Test Conditions**

For each of the calls, I changed the division number in the hope that it would avoid a "cache" as the result set would be different. So /1000,999,998 etc.

I'm sure there are people who can do far better checks and have far bigger tables to query against, but I wanted to try it.

**Conclusion**

Personally, I don't see any difference with the kind of ranges both produced - again, this could change when you multiple the data set by (n)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I see also, I'm just surprised that it is so.